# Go-routine not running when called through recursion

Tags: go

I'm doing the [Web Crawler](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10) problem from the tour of go. Here's my solution so far:

```
func GatherUrls(url string, fetcher Fetcher) []string {
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    }
    return urls
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // get all urls for depth
    // check if url has been crawled
    //  Y: noop
    //  N: crawl url
    // when depth is 0, stop
    fmt.Printf("crawling %q...\n", url)
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    urls := GatherUrls(url, fetcher)
    fmt.Println("urls:", urls)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("currentUrl:", u)
        if _, exists := cache[u]; !exists {
            fmt.Printf("about to crawl %q\n", u)
            go Crawl(u, depth - 1, fetcher)
        } else {
            cache[u] = true
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    cache = make(map[string]bool)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}
```

When I run this code, `Crawl()` is never called when the function recurses (i know this because `fmt.Printf("crawling %q...\n", url)` is only ever called once)

Here are the logs:

```
crawling "https://golang.org/"...
found: https://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
urls: [https://golang.org/pkg/ https://golang.org/cmd/]
currentUrl: https://golang.org/pkg/
about to crawl "https://golang.org/pkg/"
currentUrl: https://golang.org/cmd/
about to crawl "https://golang.org/cmd/"
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect that spawning a thread to do recursion is the wrong way to do this? Please advise.

**Please note** that I want to do this with as few libraries as possible. I've seen some answers with the `WaitGroup` package. I dont want to use this.

NOTE: The full code including the lesson boilerplate is below:
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

var cache map[string]bool

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

func GatherUrls(url string, fetcher Fetcher) []string {
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    }
    return urls
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // get all urls for depth
    // check if url has been crawled
    //  Y: noop
    //  N: crawl url
    // when depth is 0, stop
    fmt.Printf("crawling %q...\n", url)
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    urls := GatherUrls(url, fetcher)
    fmt.Println("urls:", urls)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("currentUrl:", u)
        if _, exists := cache[u]; !exists {
            fmt.Printf("about to crawl %q\n", u)
            go Crawl(u, depth - 1, fetcher)
        } else {
            cache[u] = true
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    cache = make(map[string]bool)
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: is it possible to receive messages from a channel without spawning a go routine for `GatherUrls`?

Comment: The current answers use `WaitGroup` and `Mutex` types from the standard [sync](https://godoc.org/sync) package included with all Go distributions. These are the idiomatic tools for solving the issues in the question.  It is possible to reimplement WaitGroup and Mutex using channels and thus avoid importing the sync package, but there's little point in doing that.

Comment: maybe, but i dont understand what it does. Tour of Go does not mention this package so i dont think it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: You can learn about WaitGroup by reading the [documentation](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup).  It's linked from my answer.

Comment: WaitGroups were not mentioned in Tour of Go. So I dont think they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: @dopatraman: just because you _can_ do it without wait groups, why do you have the need to reimplement such a basic part of the std library? There's a reason they are used in the majority of cases with concurrency.

Comment: There's a lot in Go that isn't mentioned in the tour. It's just a starting point to cover the most basic fundamental concepts. Limiting yourself to only what's covered in the tour will make things unnecessarily difficult, and potentially impossible.

Comment: @JimB it seems odd that one would need a concept not introduced in the lessons to complete a challenge prescribed by the lessons. Also, WaitGroups do not seem very intuitive. Why does one need to manually increment and decrement them?

Comment: @dopatraman Explicit Add/Done is required because the wait group cannot automatically determine what the application is waiting for and when it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in this sample: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10, we should do following tasks:

- Fetch URLs in parallel.
- Don't fetch the same URL twice.
- Cache URLs already fetched on a map, but maps alone are not safe for concurrent use!

So, we can do following steps to resolve above tasks:

Create struct to store the fetch result:

```
type Result struct {
    body string
    urls []string
    err  error
}
```

Create a struct to store URL has already fetched on the map, we need use `sync.Mutex`, this is not introduced in 'A Tour of Go':

```
type Cache struct {
    store map[string]bool
    mux   sync.Mutex
}
```

Fetch URL and body in parallel: Add URL to the cache when fetching it, but the first we need lock read/write in parallel by a mutex. So, we can modify `Crawl` function like this:

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }

    ch := make(chan Result)

    go func(url string, res chan Result) {
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)

        if err != nil {
            ch <- Result{body, urls, err}
            return
        }

        var furls []string
        cache.mux.Lock()
        for _, u := range urls {
            if _, exists := cache.store[u]; !exists {
                furls = append(furls, u)
            }
            cache.store[u] = true
        }
        cache.mux.Unlock()

        ch <- Result{body: body, urls: furls, err: err}

    }(url, ch)

    res := <-ch

    if res.err != nil {
        fmt.Println(res.err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, res.body)

    for _, u := range res.urls {
        Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
    }
}
```

You can view the full code and run this in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iY9uBXchx3w

Hope this help.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you for your comment. I rewrote from the original source code sample from 'A Tour of Go' to fetch URL in parallel without using wait group.

Answer (score 0):

The main() function exits before the goroutines execute.  Fix by using a [wait group](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup):

There's a data race on `cache`. Protect it with a mutex.  Always set `cache[u] = true` for URLs to be visited.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
var mu sync.Mutex
var fetched = map[string]bool{}

func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    for _, u := range urls {
        mu.Lock()
        f := fetched[u]
        fetched[u] = true
        mu.Unlock()
        if !f {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(u string) {
                defer wg.Done()
                Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
            }(u)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/18_KeE51Q3g)

[Wait groups](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) are the idiomatic way to wait for goroutines to complete.  If you cannot use [sync.WaitGroup](https://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup) for some reason, then reimplement the type using a counter, mutex and channel:

```
type WaitGroup struct {
    mu   sync.Mutex
    n    int
    done chan struct{}
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) Add(i int) {
    wg.mu.Lock()
    defer wg.mu.Unlock()
    if wg.done == nil {
        wg.done = make(chan struct{})
    }
    wg.n += i
    if wg.n < 0 {
        panic("negative count")
    }
    if wg.n == 0 {
        close(wg.done)
        wg.done = nil
    }
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) Done() {
    wg.Add(-1)
}

func (wg *WaitGroup) Wait() {
    wg.mu.Lock()
    done := wg.done
    wg.mu.Unlock()
    if done != nil {
        <-done
    }
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/dT60vutBPzq)

Comment: i dont want to use wait group

Comment: @dopatraman Updated answer includes reimplementation of sync.WaitGroup using concepts covered in the Go Tour.

Answer (score -1):

because main function was exit

you need add `sync.WaitGroup` to keep main function wait unit all coroutine done

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var cache map[string]bool

var wg sync.WaitGroup

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

func GatherUrls(url string, fetcher Fetcher, Urls chan []string) {
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    }
    Urls <- urls
    wg.Done()
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
    // get all urls for depth
    // check if url has been crawled
    //  Y: noop
    //  N: crawl url
    // when depth is 0, stop
    fmt.Printf("crawling %q... %d\n", url, depth)
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    uc := make(chan []string)
    wg.Add(1)
    go GatherUrls(url, fetcher, uc)
    urls, _ := <-uc
    fmt.Println("urls:", urls)
    for _, u := range urls {
        fmt.Println("currentUrl:", u)
        if _, exists := cache[u]; !exists {
            fmt.Printf("about to crawl %q\n", u)
            wg.Add(1)
            go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
        } else {
            cache[u] = true
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    cache = make(map[string]bool)
    wg.Add(1)
    go Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher)
    wg.Wait()
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Crawl can return without calling wg.Done().

Comment: please see the updates, i dont want to use any packages other than sync

Comment: i dont want to use any packages not mentioned in Tour of Go

Comment: @dopatraman you just write custom WaitGroup code ,but also need sync/atomic package

Comment: @bigpigeon can you provide an example of what that would look like

Comment: @dopatraman WaitGroup.Add is thread safe operation, it use sync/atomic to maintain atomicity, and sync/atomic package implement without go, if you insist on not extra package, try to make channal to sync it